Add Shift Multiplicator in VHDL Implementation?
I need to implement an add-shift multiplicator in vhdl by using the following components: PIPO, SIPO, SISO and RCA.
I know how the multiplicator works and I do know how to implement it by using a FSM (or any machine, really) but I have problems with the concrete realization. I always get uninitialized signals and I don't know what to do anymore. If this is a help, this was my FSM I used:
process(clock)
begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
        case currentCase is
            when start =>
                control_shift <= '0';
                control_add <= '0';
                control_save <= '0';
                control_clear <= '0';
                
                initial_PIPO <= p_in_1 & "0000"; -- 8Bit
                initial_SIPO <= p_in_2 & "0000";
                
                nextCase <= check; --lsb check

            when check =>
                if initial_SIPO(0) = '1' then
                    control_add <= '1'; --add
                    nextCase <= add;
                else
                    control_add <= '0';--shift
                    nextCase <= shift;
                end if;
            
            when add =>
                if control_add = '1' then
                    control_save <= '1'; --save
                else
                    control_save <= '0'; -- dont save
                end if;
                nextCase <= shift;
                
            when shift =>
            initial_SIPO <= p_in_1;
            SIPO_L_in <= '1';
            
            initial_SISO <= P_in_2;
            SISO_R_in <= '1';
            
            control_shift <= '1';
            control_clear <= '0';
            
            nextCase <= check_finish;
            
            when check_finish =>
                if initial_SIPO = "00000000" then
                    wire_PIPO_adder <= initial_PIPO;
                else
                    nextCase <= check;
                end if;
                
            when others =>
                nextCase <= start; 
        end case;
    end if;
end process;

end behavioral;

I just started with VHDL and don't know what to do anymore. If anyone knows what is wrong with it please reach out. And sorry if its too less to work with but really, any idea or just a general explanation on how to do it would be enough.
Like I said, it is a try to implement an add-shift multiplicator using vhdl and the components of a PIPO, SIPO, SISO and RCA. I hoped that it would multiply the two binary numbers p_in_1 and p_in_2 but most of the variables stayed uninitialized. I tried other stuff, like trying to initialize clock myself and such but that didn't really work. I have no clue what else I can do though and any help is appreciated, even if it is just a general push in the right direction.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to address the comments.

Do you follow some tutorial or other learning material? If so, it should have told you about initialization, for example by asynchronous reset, which is quite common. If not, this is the time to look for one that matches your knowledge level.

Since you mention you "tried other stuff", please add at least some summary of what that is.

Please provide a [mre] with the emphasis on "complete" for us to reproduce, especially for your issue of uninitialized signals. This needs to include a test bench. You might want to reduce your design to a minimum that still shows the issue. It does not need to be a multiplicator.
